# AspectJ pointcut to method from another specific method

Tags: java, aspectj

I have a class which creates an app window with some controls (the code is below, windowAs.java file). In the "initialize" class all the elements are created. Those are only few buttons from many others on the application, and all the buttons have the "actionPerformed" method with pretty similar logic behind. 
In a separate method I placed the initialization of those buttons that I'd like to include in the aspect code. All of those "special" buttons have something in common: the call to the method tableCreation with two arguments (String header[], String query). How to create a pointcut that matches the definition of those buttons?

**databaseConnection.java**:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class databaseConnectionAs {

    String query = null;

    static Connection conn = null;
    static Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    String url = null; 
    String user = null;
    String password = null; 

    List<List<String>> test_table = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    void execute_update (String query_arg) {
        if(statement != null) {
            try {
                query = query_arg;
                statement.executeUpdate(query);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to execute update: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    void execute_query (String query_arg) {
        if(statement != null) {
            try {
                query = query_arg;
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to create statement: " + e.getMessage()); 
            }
        }

       try {
            if (!resultSet.isBeforeFirst()) {
                System.out.println("resultSet empty - no data");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }


        int columnCount=0;
        try {
            test_table.clear();
            ResultSetMetaData metadata = this.resultSet.getMetaData();
            columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (this.resultSet != null) {
            try {
                int i = 0; // row counter 
                while (this.resultSet.next()) {
                    this.test_table.add(new ArrayList<String>()); // creates new line  
                    for (int j=1; j<columnCount+1; j++) { // counter for adding a new field in the row  
                        this.test_table.get(i).add(this.resultSet.getString(j)); // adding a new field in the row  
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to iterate over resultset: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    void print_results () {

        for (int i=0; i<this.test_table.size(); i++) { // from zero to number of records (rows) in a table  
            for (int j=0; j<this.test_table.get(i).size(); j++) { // from zero to number of columns  
                System.out.print(this.test_table.get(i).get(j) + " ");
            } 
            System.out.println("");
        } 
    }

}
```

**windowAs.java**:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class windowAs {

    private JFrame first_frame;
    private JTable first_table;
    private JScrollPane first_scrollpane;

    private MyButton btn_student_list;
    private MyButton btn_subjects_list;
    private MyButton btn_passed_by_students;
    private MyButton btn_passed_by_subjects;

    private JButton btn_insert;
    private JTextField txt_id;
    private JTextField txt_name;
    private JTextField txt_surname;
    private JTextField txt_year;
    private JTextField txt_error;

    // starting the app 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    windowAs window = new windowAs();
                    window.first_frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // creating the app  
    public windowAs() {
        initialize();
    }

    // initializaion of frame contents  
    private void initialize() {
        first_frame = new JFrame();
        first_frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 324);
        first_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        first_frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        first_frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        first_frame.setResizable(false);




        // adding the STUDENT LIST button 
        btn_student_list = new MyButton("Students list");
        btn_student_list.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        btn_student_list.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String header[] = new String[] {"ID", "NAME", "SURNAME", "GENDER", "YEAR"};
                String query = "SELECT studenti.student_id, studenti.student_ime, studenti.student_prezime, spol.spol_naziv, studenti.student_godina_studija FROM studenti JOIN spol ON studenti.student_spol=spol.spol_id ";
                tableCreation(header, query);
            }
        });
        btn_student_list.setBounds(10, 11, 150, 40);
        first_frame.getContentPane().add(btn_student_list);
        // end 

        // adding the SUBJECTS LIST button  
        btn_subjects_list = new MyButton("Subjects list");
        btn_subjects_list.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        btn_subjects_list.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String header[] = new String[] {"ID", "NAME", "YEAR"};
                String query = "SELECT * FROM kolegiji";
                tableCreation(header, query);
            }
        });
        btn_subjects_list.setBounds(170, 11, 150, 40);
        first_frame.getContentPane().add(btn_subjects_list);
        // end 

        // adding the PASSED BY STUDENTS button  
        btn_passed_by_students = new MyButton("Passed by students");
        btn_passed_by_students.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        btn_passed_by_students.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String header[] = new String[] {"ID", "NAME", "SURNAME", "SUBJECT ID", "NAME", "MARK"};
                String query = "SELECT studenti.student_id, studenti.student_ime, studenti.student_prezime, kolegiji.kolegij_id, kolegiji.kolegij_naziv, polozeni_kolegiji.ocjena FROM studenti JOIN polozeni_kolegiji ON studenti.student_id=polozeni_kolegiji.student_id JOIN kolegiji ON polozeni_kolegiji.kolegij_id=kolegiji.kolegij_id;";
                tableCreation(header, query);
            }
        });
        btn_passed_by_students.setBounds(10, 62, 150, 40);
        first_frame.getContentPane().add(btn_passed_by_students);
        // end  

        // adding the PASSED BY SUBJECT NAME button 
        btn_passed_by_subjects = new MyButton("Passed by subjects");
        btn_passed_by_subjects.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        btn_passed_by_subjects.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String header[] = new String[] {"JMBAG", "IME", "PREZIME", "ID KOLEGIJA", "NAZIV", "OCJENA"};
                String query = "SELECT studenti.student_id, studenti.student_ime, studenti.student_prezime, kolegiji.kolegij_id, kolegiji.kolegij_naziv, polozeni_kolegiji.ocjena FROM studenti JOIN polozeni_kolegiji ON studenti.student_id=polozeni_kolegiji.student_id JOIN kolegiji ON polozeni_kolegiji.kolegij_id=kolegiji.kolegij_id ORDER BY kolegiji.kolegij_id;";
                tableCreation(header, query);
            }
        });
        btn_passed_by_subjects.setBounds(170, 62, 150, 40);
        first_frame.getContentPane().add(btn_passed_by_subjects);
        // end 




        first_scrollpane = new JScrollPane();
        first_scrollpane.setBounds(330, 11, 454, 243);
        first_frame.getContentPane().add(first_scrollpane);

        first_table = new JTable();

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0);
        String header[] = new String[] {"LIST HERE"};
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(header);
        first_table.setModel(model);

        first_scrollpane.setViewportView(first_table);

        ButtonGroup genders = new ButtonGroup();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(10, 113, 310, 141);
        first_frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        btn_insert = new JButton("INSERT");
        btn_insert.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        btn_insert.setBounds(199, 92, 111, 39);
        panel.add(btn_insert);

        JLabel lbl_id = new JLabel("id");
        lbl_id.setBounds(0, 17, 60, 14);
        panel.add(lbl_id);

        JLabel lbl_name = new JLabel("Name");
        lbl_name.setBounds(0, 42, 60, 14);
        panel.add(lbl_name);

        JLabel lbl_surname = new JLabel("Surname");
        lbl_surname.setBounds(0, 67, 60, 14);
        panel.add(lbl_surname);

        JLabel lbl_gender = new JLabel("Gender");
        lbl_gender.setBounds(0, 92, 60, 14);
        panel.add(lbl_gender);

        JLabel lbl_year = new JLabel("Year");
        lbl_year.setBounds(0, 117, 60, 14);
        panel.add(lbl_year);

        txt_id = new JTextField();
        txt_id.setBounds(69, 11, 241, 20);
        panel.add(txt_id);
        txt_id.setColumns(10);

        txt_name = new JTextField();
        txt_name.setBounds(69, 36, 241, 20);
        panel.add(txt_name);
        txt_name.setColumns(10);

        txt_surname = new JTextField();
        txt_surname.setBounds(69, 61, 241, 20);
        panel.add(txt_surname);
        txt_surname.setColumns(10);

        JRadioButton rdbtn_m = new JRadioButton("M");
        rdbtn_m.setBounds(69, 88, 50, 23);
        panel.add(rdbtn_m);
        genders.add(rdbtn_m);

        JRadioButton rdbtn_f = new JRadioButton("F");
        rdbtn_f.setBounds(140, 88, 50, 23);
        panel.add(rdbtn_f);
        genders.add(rdbtn_f);

        txt_year = new JTextField();
        txt_year.setBounds(69, 111, 120, 20);
        panel.add(txt_year);
        txt_year.setColumns(10);

        btn_insert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    int id = Integer.parseInt(txt_id.getText());
                    String name = txt_name.getText();
                    String surname = txt_surname.getText(); 
                    int year = Integer.parseInt(txt_year.getText());
                    int gender = 0;
                    if (rdbtn_m.isSelected()) {
                        gender = 1;
                    }
                    else if (rdbtn_f.isSelected()) {
                        gender = 2;
                    }

                    databaseConnectionAs conn = new databaseConnectionAs();
                    String query = "INSERT INTO studenti VALUES ('" + id + "', '" + name + "', '" + surname + "', '" + gender + "', '" + year + "');";
                    conn.execute_update(query);

                } catch (Exception er) {
                    txt_error.setVisible(true);
                    txt_error.setEditable(false);
                    txt_error.setText("Error: " + er.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        txt_error = new JTextField();
        txt_error.setBounds(10, 265, 774, 23);
        first_frame.getContentPane().add(txt_error);
        txt_error.setColumns(10);
        txt_error.setVisible(false);

    }


    public void tableCreation (String header[], String query) {
        databaseConnectionAs conn = new databaseConnectionAs();

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0);
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(header);
        first_table.setModel(model);

        conn.execute_query(query);
        for (int i=0; i<conn.test_table.size(); i++) {
            model.addRow(new Object[]{});
            for (int j=0; j<conn.test_table.get(i).size(); j++) {
                model.setValueAt(conn.test_table.get(i).get(j), i, j);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**MyButton.java**:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class MyButton extends JButton {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyButton(String string) {
        setText(string);
    }

}
```

**databaseAspect.aj**:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public aspect databaseAspect {

    pointcut myConnection() : execution(* execute_query(..)) || execution(* execute_update(..));

    // advice to open the connection and statement creation before accessing the database  
    before() : myConnection() {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/testbaza"; 
        String user = "testkorisnik";
        String password = "testlozinka";

        try {
            databaseConnectionAs.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("\nUnable to connect to database: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (databaseConnectionAs.conn != null) {
            try {
                databaseConnectionAs.statement = databaseConnectionAs.conn.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to create statement: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    // advice to close the connection after finishing the query  
    after() : myConnection() {
        try {
            databaseConnectionAs.conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("\nError while disconnecting the database: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    pointcut click() : execution(* actionPerformed(..)) && within(MyButton..*); 

    after() : click() {
        System.out.println("You did it!");
    }


}
```

**testbaza.sql**:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.2.11
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Jul 15, 2015 at 01:16 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.21
-- PHP Version: 5.6.3

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `testbaza`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `kolegiji`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `kolegiji` (
`kolegij_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `kolegij_naziv` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `kolegij_godina` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `kolegiji`
--

INSERT INTO `kolegiji` (`kolegij_id`, `kolegij_naziv`, `kolegij_godina`) VALUES
(1, 'Financijska Matematika', 1),
(2, 'Marketing', 1),
(3, 'Marketing', 1),
(4, 'Statistika', 1),
(5, 'Trgovacko Pravo', 1),
(6, 'Informaticko Pravo', 1),
(7, 'Ured I Uredsko Poslovanje', 1),
(8, 'Baze Podataka', 2),
(9, 'Informatika u Primjeni', 2),
(10, 'Kvantitativni Menadzment', 2),
(11, 'Matematicke Metode za Poslovne Analize', 2),
(12, 'Poslovni Informacijski Sustavi Drzvane Uprave', 2),
(13, 'Elektronicko Poslovanje', 2),
(14, 'Financije Malih i Srednjih Poduzeca', 1),
(15, 'IS Malih i Srednjih Poduzeca', 1),
(16, 'Kontroling i Politika Kvalitete', 2),
(17, 'Medunarodna Trgovina', 1),
(18, 'Transport Spedicija i Osiguranje', 1),
(19, 'Izgradnja Web Aplikacija', 3),
(20, 'Modeliranje Poslovnih Pravila', 3),
(21, 'Multimedijski Sustavi', 3),
(22, 'Napredno Programiranje', 3),
(23, 'Poslovno Planiranje', 3),
(24, 'Primjena Mreznih Servisa', 3),
(25, 'Programiranje', 3),
(26, 'Sigurnost Informacijskih Sustava', 3),
(27, 'Upravljanje Informatickim Uslugama', 3),
(28, 'Engleski 1', 1),
(29, 'Informatika 1', 1),
(30, 'Engleski 2', 2),
(31, 'Informatika 2', 2),
(32, 'Obrada Teksta i Slike', 1),
(33, 'Organizacija', 1),
(34, 'Osnove Ekonomije', 1),
(35, 'Poslovno Komuniciranje', 1),
(36, 'Statistika', 1),
(37, 'Matematika 1', 1),
(38, 'Racunovodstvo', 2),
(39, 'Teorija Sustava', 2),
(40, 'Marketing', 3),
(41, 'Ergonomija', 4),
(42, 'IS u Potpori Upravljanju i Odlucivanju', 4),
(43, 'Razvoj IS', 4),
(44, 'Ekonomika', 4),
(45, 'Dinamicke Web Aplikacije', 4),
(46, 'Management Kvalitete', 4),
(47, 'Softversko Inzenjerstvo', 4),
(48, 'Teorija Informacija', 4),
(49, 'ICT i Drustvo', 5),
(50, 'Informacijski Management', 5),
(51, 'Modeliranje i Simulacija', 5),
(52, 'Poduzetnistvo i Gospodarstvo', 5);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `polozeni_kolegiji`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `polozeni_kolegiji` (
  `student_id` bigint(10) NOT NULL,
  `kolegij_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `ocjena` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `polozeni_kolegiji`
--

INSERT INTO `polozeni_kolegiji` (`student_id`, `kolegij_id`, `ocjena`) VALUES
(1394984532, 1, 3),
(1394984532, 2, 5),
(1394984532, 3, 2),
(1394984532, 4, 2),
(1394984532, 5, 5),
(1394984532, 6, 3),
(1394984532, 7, 3),
(1394984532, 14, 5),
(1394984532, 15, 4),
(1394984532, 17, 4),
(1394984532, 18, 2),
(1473419155, 1, 2),
(1473419155, 2, 4),
(1473419155, 3, 3),
(1473419155, 4, 4),
(1473419155, 5, 2),
(1473419155, 6, 3),
(1473419155, 7, 3),
(1473419155, 8, 4),
(1473419155, 9, 2),
(1473419155, 10, 3),
(1473419155, 11, 3),
(1473419155, 12, 5),
(1473419155, 13, 5),
(1473419155, 14, 3),
(1473419155, 15, 3),
(1473419155, 16, 4),
(1473419155, 17, 3),
(1473419155, 18, 5),
(1473419155, 19, 5),
(1473419155, 20, 2),
(1473419155, 21, 4),
(1473419155, 22, 2),
(1473419155, 23, 4),
(1473419155, 24, 3),
(1473419155, 25, 5),
(1473419155, 26, 5),
(1473419155, 27, 4),
(1473419155, 28, 3),
(1473419155, 29, 2),
(1473419155, 30, 2),
(1473419155, 31, 2),
(1473419155, 32, 2),
(1473419155, 33, 5),
(1473419155, 34, 3),
(1473419155, 35, 5),
(1473419155, 36, 5),
(1473419155, 37, 4),
(1473419155, 38, 4),
(1473419155, 39, 5),
(1473419155, 40, 2),
(1876743912, 1, 5),
(1876743912, 2, 4),
(1876743912, 3, 4),
(1876743912, 4, 4),
(1876743912, 5, 2),
(1876743912, 6, 5),
(1876743912, 7, 2),
(1876743912, 14, 4),
(1876743912, 15, 5),
(1876743912, 17, 5),
(1876743912, 18, 5),
(1876743912, 28, 5),
(1876743912, 29, 5),
(1876743912, 32, 5),
(1876743912, 33, 4),
(1876743912, 34, 5),
(1876743912, 35, 5),
(1876743912, 36, 4),
(1876743912, 37, 5),
(2131875260, 1, 5),
(2131875260, 2, 2),
(2131875260, 3, 3),
(2131875260, 4, 2),
(2131875260, 5, 4),
(2131875260, 6, 3),
(2131875260, 7, 4),
(2131875260, 14, 5),
(2131875260, 15, 4),
(2131875260, 17, 2),
(2131875260, 18, 5),
(2131875260, 28, 4),
(2131875260, 29, 4),
(2131875260, 32, 5),
(2131875260, 33, 4),
(2131875260, 34, 3),
(2131875260, 35, 3),
(2131875260, 36, 4),
(2131875260, 37, 3),
(2517879602, 1, 2),
(2517879602, 2, 3),
(2517879602, 3, 3),
(2517879602, 4, 3),
(2517879602, 5, 4),
(2517879602, 6, 2),
(2517879602, 7, 2),
(2517879602, 8, 2),
(2517879602, 9, 2),
(2517879602, 10, 2),
(2517879602, 11, 4),
(2517879602, 12, 5),
(2517879602, 13, 4),
(2517879602, 14, 3),
(2517879602, 15, 5),
(2517879602, 16, 5),
(2517879602, 17, 2),
(2517879602, 18, 4),
(2517879602, 28, 3),
(2517879602, 29, 2),
(2517879602, 30, 5),
(2517879602, 31, 5),
(2517879602, 32, 2),
(2517879602, 33, 4),
(2517879602, 34, 5),
(2517879602, 35, 4),
(2517879602, 36, 2),
(2517879602, 37, 3),
(2517879602, 38, 5),
(2517879602, 39, 2),
(2936048095, 1, 2),
(2936048095, 2, 5),
(2936048095, 3, 3),
(2936048095, 4, 5),
(2936048095, 5, 4),
(2936048095, 6, 4),
(2936048095, 7, 2),
(2936048095, 14, 5),
(2936048095, 15, 5),
(2936048095, 17, 3),
(2936048095, 18, 3),
(2936048095, 28, 5),
(2936048095, 29, 2),
(2936048095, 32, 5),
(2936048095, 33, 5),
(2936048095, 34, 3),
(2936048095, 35, 4),
(2936048095, 36, 5),
(2936048095, 37, 3),
(3736706852, 1, 5),
(3736706852, 2, 4),
(3736706852, 3, 2),
(3736706852, 4, 2),
(3736706852, 5, 4),
(3736706852, 6, 3),
(3736706852, 7, 4),
(3736706852, 8, 4),
(3736706852, 9, 5),
(3736706852, 10, 2),
(3736706852, 11, 2),
(3736706852, 12, 4),
(3736706852, 13, 2),
(3736706852, 14, 3),
(3736706852, 15, 4),
(3736706852, 16, 4),
(3736706852, 17, 3),
(3736706852, 18, 5),
(3736706852, 19, 2),
(3736706852, 20, 5),
(3736706852, 21, 3),
(3736706852, 22, 5),
(3736706852, 23, 4),
(3736706852, 24, 4),
(3736706852, 25, 3),
(3736706852, 26, 5),
(3736706852, 27, 5),
(3736706852, 28, 3),
(3736706852, 29, 2),
(3736706852, 30, 4),
(3736706852, 31, 3),
(3736706852, 32, 3),
(3736706852, 33, 4),
(3736706852, 34, 3),
(3736706852, 35, 5),
(3736706852, 36, 3),
(3736706852, 37, 3),
(3736706852, 38, 5),
(3736706852, 39, 2),
(3736706852, 40, 4),

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `spol`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `spol` (
  `spol_id` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spol_naziv` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `spol`
--

INSERT INTO `spol` (`spol_id`, `spol_naziv`) VALUES
(1, 'musko'),
(2, 'zensko');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `studenti`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `studenti` (
  `student_id` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `student_ime` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `student_prezime` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `student_spol` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `student_godina_studija` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `studenti`
--

INSERT INTO `studenti` (`student_id`, `student_ime`, `student_prezime`, `student_spol`, `student_godina_studija`) VALUES
(1394984532, 'Mario', 'Kos', 1, 2),
(1473419155, 'Alen', 'Katic', 1, 4),
(1876743912, 'Darija', 'Popovic', 2, 2),
(2131875260, 'Vlatka', 'Marusic', 2, 2),
(2517879602, 'Jelica', 'Miletic', 2, 3),
(2801676037, 'Milovan', 'Ceh', 1, 1),
(2936048095, 'Vladimir', 'Peric', 1, 2),
(3477826494, 'Aleksandra', 'Novosel', 2, 1),
(3736706852, 'Zeljka', 'Stanic', 2, 4),

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `testna_tablica`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testna_tablica` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `ime` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `prezime` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `testna_tablica`
--

INSERT INTO `testna_tablica` (`id`, `ime`, `prezime`) VALUES
(1, 'Ivo', 'Ivic'),
(2, 'Ana', 'Anic'),
(3, 'Pero', 'Peric'),
(4, 'Marko', 'Markic');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `test_upisivanja`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_upisivanja` (
  `prvi` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `drugi` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `kolegiji`
--
ALTER TABLE `kolegiji`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`kolegij_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `polozeni_kolegiji`
--
ALTER TABLE `polozeni_kolegiji`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`,`kolegij_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `studenti`
--
ALTER TABLE `studenti`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `testna_tablica`
--
ALTER TABLE `testna_tablica`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `kolegiji`
--
ALTER TABLE `kolegiji`
MODIFY `kolegij_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=53;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: First question I would ask is: Why? It's not a cross cutting concern, it's common functionality, so why use aspects? The last part of each piece of code is common, so put that into a method and call that from the various `actionPerformed()`.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are actually trying to achieve. You are describing the structure of your code but not what you want to do. Help me understand your question, then I might be able to help you solve your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to write an example app to show the same thing done with and without aspects. 
I'm looking to replace all the calls to a method doSTG() with a single aspect that would automatically be included after clicking a button. 
As Andy Clement advised, I should use a around advice, but I cannot seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to do this with aspects you would use `around` advice when you are looking to replace something that is going to happen. `before` and `after` do not affect what is going to happen.

```
pointcut click() : execution (* actionPerformed(..));

void around() : click() {
    // the code in here will run instead of the actionPerformed method body
    // If you make a proceed call, that will run the original body
    // proceed();
}
```

More info at: https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-advice.html

Comment: Thanks for Your suggestion. I edited the top post to be more specific. I really cannot seem to make it work. Could You please give me a hand?

Comment: Few observations. Your withincode pointcut doesn't look right because actionPerformed takes a parameter, you need to add one (or wildcard it) to match. Then the call to doSTG() happens within your actionPerformed() method but the execution of doSTG() does not, that happens wherever doSTG is declared.  You could: call(* doSTG()) && withincode(* actionPerformed(..)) or you could execution(* doSTG()) && cflow(execution(* actionPerformed(..))) - this latter one says you are interested in when doSTG() runs in the control flow of an actionPerformed method.

Comment: Thank for Your help so far. I think You got me wrong. This works: /** pointcut click() : execution(* actionPerformed(..)) **/ 
But it works on ALL clicks of a any button. I don't want it to work on all buttons - I want that it affects only those buttons that are declared in the specialButtons() method.

Comment: Limiting it to just those created in specialButtons() is tricky. Limiting it to those created with the class MyApp is easier - would that be ok for you? (Maybe it is if all the others are created in other classes).  In which case: execution(* actionPerformed(..)) && within(MyApp..*) will work.

Comment: Tnx for trying so far.....
1)..... I created a class (new file):  
public class MyButton extends JButton {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public MyButton(String string) {
setText(string);
}}
.....2)..... In the main MyApp file: 
private MyButton btn1;
private MyButton btn2;
btn1 = new MyButton("Test 1");
btn2 = new MyButton("Test 2");

.....3)..... Pointcut: 
pointcut klik() : execution(* actionPerformed(..)) && within(MyButton..*); 
after() : klik() {
System.out.println("Test: clicked it!"); }

Error: advice defined in MyAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]

Comment: That is a bit tricky to read - the error indicates the pointcut does not match. From the snippet there, MyButton doesn't define an actionPerformed() method so it won't be matched by the pointcut. Sure the pointcut shouldn't be within(MyApp..*) ? (presuming MyApp is as above)

Comment: Thanks Andy. I know it was very tricky to read (I still got to figure out the formatting in comments...). 

I edited the main post: I added the most important code from my app (including the SQL DB) so You can get an idea of my actual code. Can You please try to explain how should the pointcut in databaseAspect.aj file be declared so that it matches only the buttons (1) btn_student_list, (2) btn_subjects_list, (3) btn_passed_by_students and (4) btn_passed_by_subjects created in the windowAs.java file? 

Thank You very much for Your help so far :)

Comment: Instead of `pointcut click() : execution(* actionPerformed(..)) && within(MyButton..*);` you want something like `pointcut click(): execution(* actionPerformedn(..)) && within(windowAs*)`. Think about the name that gets generated for the button handler anonymous classes, it'll be something like `windowAs$1` (you will see them on disk after compiling that code) - that is what you are trying to capture with the `within()` clause.

Comment: I tried `pointcut click() : execution(* actionPerformed(..)) && within(windowAs*);`... it captures all calls to the `actionPerformed` method. Still not capturing only those from buttons created within the `MyButton.java` class...

Comment: Think I'm misunderstanding what you precisely want, sorry I've been reading it too quickly. If your condition is "I want to match creation of a button that gets an actionListener later on that contains a tableCreation call" - you can't really do that as the join points are too disconnected, you need an easier to recognize condition: a call to addActionListener on a target of MyButton perhaps? (If you can do your extra initialization lazily you could do it on this event occurring, but you can't tell if that action listener calls tableCreation).

Comment: (1) I want to put the code from the `tableCreation()` method into an advice body. 
(2) That advice should be called when only CERTAIN buttons are pressed - buttons which actually need this advice are the ones that populate the table. 
(3) As You suggested, I've put those buttons in a separate `MyButton.java` class....
I don't want to match the CREATION of a button, but the click of those buttons... 
Finally, my condition: pointcut should identify the click of the buttons that are members/instances of the `MyButton.java` class...
If You think there is a better approach, I am willing to hear :)

Comment: Any ideas @AndyClement?

Comment: As you have your own MyButton now that encapsulates the buttons you are interested in - can you not override the addActionListener method? Then have that method call super.addActionListener() with a wrapper action that delegates to the original passed into addActionListener and then calls tableCreation()?

Comment: Honestly, that's far above my current knowledge and therefore I don't understand the vast majority of what You just said. I thought it would be easier to just create a pointcut which would select those methods, but I just can't figure it out...

Comment: I thought it would be possible to make something like this: `pointcut click() : execution(* MyButton.addActionListener.actionPerformed(..))` or something like it.

Comment: My previous proposed solution just doesn't need aspects to do what you want (but only if I understand what you want). execution() pointcuts take a declared method. What you have there is not a declared method. If you overrode 'addActionListener' in MyButton then that part would exist then you could then do execution(* MyButton.addActionListener(..)) to get you the action listener but i know that isn't quite sufficient. Maybe if you switch over to using the aspectj mailing list I could write out code more easily (I'm always on there), I can't fit stuff in these little boxes :)